# there's something wrong with my controller codes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TechnicianFacade _oTechFacade = new TechnicianFacade();
    Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel _oTechModel = new Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel();
    IList<Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel> _otechList = new List<Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel>();

    var tech = _oTechFacade.getTechnicians("", _oAppSetting.ConnectionString).ToArray();
    foreach (var test in tech)
    {
       string fName = test.GetType().GetProperty("FIRSTNAME").GetValue(test, null).ToString();
        _oTechModel.firstName = fName;
        _otechList.Add(_oTechModel);         <===
    }
    _oTechModel.fNameList = _otechList;
    return View("Index", _oTechModel);                                 
}
```

In my controller: index, can get all data object from my database. But if I have more than one data object in my database the: _otechList.Add(_otechModel) will overwrite the first entry with the newly added data, like for example lets just say we have 2 object data: (FIRST loop of foreach) *_otechList.Add(_oTechModel)* has a data of **"FIRSTNAME" = "GEM"** where count = 0, (SECOND loop of foreach) *_otechList.Add(_oTechModel)* has a data of **"FIRSTNAME" = "DIAMOND"** where count = 1, this time the value of count[0] became **"FIRSTNAME" = "DIAMOND"** as well. Is there something missing in my code or there's something wrong on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will replace because same object value is changed, you need to instantiate object inside foreach loop.

```
Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel _oTechModel = new Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel();
```

like this:

```
foreach (var test in tech)
    {
       string fName = test.GetType().GetProperty("FIRSTNAME").GetValue(test, null).ToString();
        Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel _oTechModel = new Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel();
        _oTechModel.firstName = fName;
        _otechList.Add(_oTechModel);        
    }
```

your `object` is global so every time same `object` is added in the list, instantiate it inside **foreach** loop so that every time new `object` is added in the list.